# How to make freestyle look hand drawn?

Tags: rendering, texturing, freestyle, npr

I'm still learning blender 3d so I'm sorry if this is hard to understand.

I'm trying to edit the stroke/textures on the freestyle editor so where it looks hand drawn/sketchy I'm hoping to get some result like this https://youtu.be/5jZvFuaNNlY but I'm still new to blender and I know nothing about textures.

I heard about uv mapping but I don't know what to do with it when it comes to freestyle lines.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, *Freestyle* doesn't stylize shading, only affects geometry lines (correct me if I am wrong). You can combine *Freestyle* lines in compositor with shading converted to strokes.

Basic plan for shading is to separate simple material to shading layers, and assign "stroke" textures with different density/color/orientation in according with these shading layers.

You can separate shading to layers inside materials using *ColorRamp* node. (Pic is not mine, taken from [tutorial](http://blendernpr.org/cross-hatch-shader/))

[image]

Also check *.Blend* file example on Blender site [here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.67/FreeStyle) (Blue Pencil Shark at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the freestyle setting I used to get the line looks below. Also **enable Ambient Occlusion**.  Rendered using EEVEE in about 13 seconds using Blender 3.4.1

**Original**

[image: img1]

**Hand Drawn look:**

[image: img2]

**Settings:**

[image: img3]

**Another one:**

[image: img4]

**Settings:**

[image: img5]